# PHP: Forcing a download not working

Tags: php

I have the following code to push a zip file for download.

```
$filename = "ResourcePack_".time().".zip";
        $destination = $basepath."downloads/$filename";
        if($this->createdownload($files,$destination,false)){
            header("Cache-Control: public");
            header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
            header("Content-Length: ". filesize("$destination").";");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$filename'");
            header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
            ob_end_flush();
            @readfile($destination);

            if(file_exists($destination)){
                unlink($destination);
            }
        }
```

I know the createdownload function is working to generate the zip file just fine because I see the file being created on the server. The problem is file is being written to the browser as a bunch of garbage instead of opening a download stream. Am I missing something in my headers?

## EDIT

I was right. My problem is not with the php, but that calling the php file that generates this code via a JQuery $.ajax call is the problem. Using $.ajax automatically sets the Accept-Encoding request header to values incompatible with zip files. So, intead of using $.ajax I just used a simple window.open javascript command to call the same php page and it works just fine with the headers.

Comment: Try reading the manual for header(). There are tons of functions people have made for forcing a download such as http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#102175

Comment: Why not check if the file exists before even starting? Because if it doesn't exist, `filesize` will fail.

Comment: I've read it backword and forward. My code matches up with a number of other places as far as I can tell. I'm here because if there is something in the manual to help me fix this I'm missing it.

Comment: notice the `if($this->createdownload` statement. createdownload returns true if the zip file is successfully created. As I stated above I checked the server to make sure the file is created.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the problem the problem is that this function is called via a jquery $.ajax call. This sets the Accept-Encoding header automatically to incompatible encoding types. Now I'm trying to see if there's a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

try passing proper type for that file. I think its fileinfo mime type see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php

```
header("Content-Type: $file_type");
```

Also you have semicolon after octet-stream remove it

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
```

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. I was wondering if this could be related to the request headers. The request headers say: `Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch` but the Response header type is `binary`. Could this be causing a problem?

Comment: Updated answer about you having a semicolon

Comment: maybe, text from php documentation (header page) "Also, be aware that IE versions 5, 6, 7, and 8 double-compress already-compressed files and do not reverse the process correctly, so ZIP files and similar are corrupted on download.

Workaround: disable compression (beyond text/html) for these particular versions of IE, e.g., using Apache's "BrowserMatch" directive. The following example disables compression in all versions of IE:"   http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php#108766

Answer (score 0):

try to put a die after the @readfile
and remove the @, to see if you have any other error related with the file reading.

i have some code doing the same thing and this works for me:

```
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private", false); // required for certain browsers
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
        header('Content-type: application/zip');
        //header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($destination));

        readfile($destination);
        die();
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work work for me. No error from the die either.